# Eclipse / CDT auto-indent on new line only incorrect for structs?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, indentation, stm32cubeide

Using new Eclipse and CDT versions built into STM32CubeIDE. I have the built in formatter options adjusted and use clang-format as my main beautifier. Everywhere I can see in the `Window` >> `Preferences` menus I have indent turned to 2 spaces-only.

Next line indent works correctly with everything but structs which the indentation seems to be doubled.

It doesn't seem to be indenting 2 units twice, because pressing tab moves me 4 spaces while inside a struct block. Clang-Format with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> does fix the incorrect formatting, but I'd rather a proper solution.

Either it's a bug, or somewhere this is yet another setting for *"4 space indent but only while inside a struct block"*?

See examples:

```
typedef struct
{

    //New lines created inside the block start here, indented at 4 and not 2

    //I get here if I press tab from the start column 

  //This is where it should intent to, manually pressed spaced twice

} some_new_t;



void foo()
{
  //Correct
}

if (something)
{
  //Correct
}

while(1)
{
  //Correct
}

#ifdef TEST
//Doesn't indent, that's fine
#endif
```

EDIT: Applies to unions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This was not a 2 spaces vs 4 spaces issue, rather double indent when you only wanted one.

For some reason CDT has a lot more references to C++ and still Java than C and this was labeled under something misleading.

Under `Window`, `Preferences`, `C/C++`, `Code Style`, `Formatter` >> `Edit` >> `Indentation` >> `Indent` there are two options that can be checked.

`'public', 'protected', 'private' within class body`

and

`Declarations relative to 'public' 'private'`

You can check ONLY ONE of these for C structures and unions to indent at your chosen width. For whatever non-C reason, each one counts as including one indent width.

[image: Eclipse formatter indents too much on C structures and unions]